# What would I use to convert a signal in my project?

Tags: microcontroller, led

The PlayStation 4 Pro and PlayStation 5 have orange, blue and white leds to indicate the status of the console.

Boot - Blue

Idle - White

Rest - Orange

The PS4 Pro / PS5 leds and their transistors are on a separate pcb connected by a 6 pin ribbon cable.

What I want to do is replace the white and orange leds with red and green so that I can output any color of my choosing at each state. To do this i'm guessing I need some kind of micro controller pcb programmed with a custom script. To be placed between the PlayStation motherboard and the led pcb.

**Technical Details:**

1. The leds are always connected to 5v.
2. Each led signal goes to the base pin of an unknown model transistor .
3. When each led is fully on the transistor base pin gets 3.3v and 450 microAmps.
4. When the led pulses it goes between 0-3.3v and 0-450 microAmps on the transistor base pin.

Obviously I need to emulate the signal each transistors base pin is expecting with the micro controller.

---

***Example:***

Lets assume the leds are now:

Boot - Blue

Idle - Green

Rest - Red

So if I want my idle state led to be purple (R+B=Purple) I need to tell the micro controller  when it sees a 3.3v 450 microAmp signal on the idle led input pin to output a 3.3v 450 microAmp signal on both the blue and red led transistor base output pins.

---

Does this sound like something that can be easily done with readily available cheap micro controllers, if so what would you recommend?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, but have you considered changing the LEDs to the colours you want?

Comment: does your board look like this? https://guide-images.cdn.ifixit.com/igi/b2CSvIbAs2Pfx2Zr.huge

Answer (score 1):

Your question is formulated with some ambiguity. Therefore, I'm trying to come up with an answer whilst stating my assumptions.

**(1)** Assumptions: The LED-PCB is connected and driven in the original PS4/5 as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGEYZa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- The LED Signals are PWM modulated to control the brightness (Sig_A - Sig_C).
- The logic Signals are not inverted (Sig_A = 1 == Led_A = 1)

**(2)** Problems:

- The first problem is, that the Front-PCB does not have a continuous 3V3 logic-supply. Therefore, the uC to convert the signals is not always powered on!
- The LED-Signals are driven LOW via an NPN - otherwise they are High-Z.
- I'm guessing, that the 3V3 Lins are driven activly also. Otherwise, a 4-Way Ribbon would have been used most likely (Cheaper).

**(3)** Solution:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGEoK9.png)</sup>

- You'll need to connect a continuous 3V3 and GND cable within your PS4/5 to make this possible. You can use some standard wire and solder it to the Main-PCB.
- You then can use a uC to sense the Signals (Caution: Logic is inverted through the Pullups) and make sense of them within Software (Measure PWM Value). The LEDs you want to use are driven bei the uC directly.

**(4)** Notes:

- You can use either a cheap Micro (Atmel AVR, PIC, .... ) or an CPLD/FPGA (Xilinx e.g.)
- You'll need to design an PCB
- Programming the uC in (C or C++) sounds easy at first, but you'll have to do some advanced stuff to decode the PWM values correctly and generate the three PWM signals for the LEDs.
- You'll need to solder to the main PCB of the PS4/5 which can **damage** the unit.

Comment: The separate PCB contains the leds, their transistors and the always on 5v.